# Can't [sharepoint-clientobject] share with [client-object-model]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The two tags [client-object-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/client-object-model) and [sharepoint-clientobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-clientobject) are relating to the same thing (The [SharePoint Client Object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx)) and I believe should be merged.

Comment: I agree and think [sharepoint-clientobject] should be kept, it is a more informative name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think they should be merged as both tag wikis are exactly the same except for a manual tag synonym link at the end of each wiki.  I have to agree with  [JasonMArcher](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/64046/jasonmarcher) that [sharepoint-clientobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-clientobject) should be kept as it is a more informative name.

Comment: Since this seems to be the common opinion - what's the next step? I'm only on 2k reputation so I can't make any tag changes.

Comment: @Codingo I believe a mod has to do it.